# How can I add video in carousel using react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to add video in the carousel but not able to add properly.i have tried HTML5 video tag but it doesn't work. i have used iframe also but that doesn't solve my requirement can anybody please tell me how can i implement video in carousel instead of image

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Carousel } from "react-bootstrap";
class Slider extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
       <Carousel>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      style={{width:"400px",height:"400px"}}
      src="https://img.rawpixel.com/s3fs-private/rawpixel_images/website_content/pf-mu6-ake6324-chim-l.jpg?w=800&dpr=1&fit=default&crop=default&auto=format&fm=pjpg&q=75&vib=3&con=3&usm=15&bg=F4F4F3&ixlib=js-2.2.1&s=7edc252958c9c6b9cea5379443d6ac46"
      alt="First slide"
    />

  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      style={{width:"400px",height:"400px"}}
      src="https://img.rawpixel.com/s3fs-private/rawpixel_images/website_content/pf-mu6-ake6324-chim-l.jpg?w=800&dpr=1&fit=default&crop=default&auto=format&fm=pjpg&q=75&vib=3&con=3&usm=15&bg=F4F4F3&ixlib=js-2.2.1&s=7edc252958c9c6b9cea5379443d6ac46"
      alt="Third slide"
    />


  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
   <video style ={{width:"400px",height:"400px"}}>
       <source src="https://youtu.be/r0DYJzN00B4" type="video/mp4"></source>
   </video>


  </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Slider;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a parent div to video tag and check if it works.

```
 <div className="video-section">
 <video style ={{width:"400px",height:"400px"}}>
       <source src="https://youtu.be/r0DYJzN00B4" type="video/mp4"></source>
   </video>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, i tried and this worked but there are few an attributes have to be use in video element tag
eg controls , loop , autoPlay

Answer (score 1):

add controls attribute to video tag.

```html
<Carousel>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <video style={{height:360,width:'100%'}} controls>
                            <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4" 
type="video/mp4"></source>
                            Sorry, your browser doesn't support videos.
                        </video>
                        <Carousel.Caption>
                            <h3>First slide label</h3>
                            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                        </Carousel.Caption>
                    </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```